# Cleaning up tags for Castlevania

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-rename-request

There are several tags in the Castlevania series which could use some renaming now that we have 35 characters.

- [castlevania-cotm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-cotm) -> [castlevania-circle-of-the-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-circle-of-the-moon)
- [castlevania-ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-ds) -> [castlevania-dawn-of-sorrow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-dawn-of-sorrow)
- [castlevania-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-hd) -> [castlevania-harmony-of-despair](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-harmony-of-despair)
- [castlevania-los](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-los) -> [castlevania-lords-of-shadow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-lords-of-shadow)
- [castlevania-los-mof](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-los-mof) -> [castlevania-lords-of-shadow-mof](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-lords-of-shadow-mof)
- [castlevania-ooe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-ooe) -> [castlevania-order-of-ecclesia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-order-of-ecclesia)
- [castlevania-sotn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-sotn) -> [castlevania-symphony-of-the-night](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-symphony-of-the-night)
- [castlevania-tdxc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-tdxc) -> [castlevania-dracula-x-chronicles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-dracula-x-chronicles)

Anyone against renaming these?

Comment: Clearing abbreviations is always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done:

- [castlevania-cotm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-cotm) -> [castlevania-circle-of-the-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-circle-of-the-moon)
- [castlevania-ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-ds) -> [castlevania-dawn-of-sorrow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-dawn-of-sorrow)
- [castlevania-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-hd) -> [castlevania-harmony-of-despair](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-harmony-of-despair)
- [castlevania-los](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-los) -> [castlevania-lords-of-shadow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-lords-of-shadow)
- [castlevania-los-mof](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-los-mof) -> [castlevania-lords-of-shadow-mof](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-lords-of-shadow-mof)
- [castlevania-ooe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-ooe) -> [castlevania-order-of-ecclesia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-order-of-ecclesia)
- [castlevania-sotn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-sotn) -> [castlevania-symphony-of-the-night](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-symphony-of-the-night)
- [castlevania-tdxc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-tdxc) -> [castlevania-dracula-x-chronicles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-dracula-x-chronicles)